# HTML e-mail Signature Problem with various e-mails

Tags: html, css, email, signature

I am trying to create my own HTML signature and I thought I did, as a matter of fact but It seems that it works just for my e-mail client (Thunderbird). After testing the same HTML on Outlook, it showed differently. Thus, since I am not an expert in HTML, I would like some assistance. The following image shows the ideal scenario

#### IDEAL SCENARIO (Thunderbird)

[[image: Ideal Scenario (Mozilla thunderbird)][Thunderbird view]

and the code is the following one:

```
<html>


    <body style="background-color:white;">
    
            <div>
            <p style="float: left;">
<img src="path/to/img1", width="130" height="130">  
            </p>
            <p style="font-family: 'courier new';font-size: 11px;">
            <br> 
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
            <b style="font-size:13px">Name Surname</b><br>
            <br>
            Occupation<br>
            Building|<br>
            Address |<br>
            <a href="www.google.gr"> A dummy href </a> | e-mail: <a href="mailto:my-email@my-domain">my-email@my-domain</a>
            </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <br>
            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.researchgate.net/profile"> <img src="path/to/RG/icon", width="32" height="32"> </a>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/profile"> <img src="path/to/LINKDIN/icon", width="32" height="32"></a>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.github.com/prof/"> <img src="path/to/GH/icon", width="32" height="32" </a>
            
    </body>
    
    <style>
        hr {

            background: linear-gradient(to right,#ff0000,#ff4000,#ffff00,#ffff33,#40ff00,#00ff00,#00ffff,#00bfff);
            height: 3px;
            width: 410px;
            float: left;
            margin-top:0;
            margin-bottom:2;
           }
    
    </style>
</html>
```

#### Erroneous Scenario

When I saw how it shows on Outlook or Windows Mail I saw this:
[[image][Outlook view]

The `name surname` , `misc info`, `color gradient` everything is displaced. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: github's `<img src="path/to/GH/icon", width="32" height="32"` don't have closing `>`

Comment: @rzlvmp fixed! But how about the discrepancy on the (i) positioning (ii) gradient bar